# Bayesian statistics: Write up unnormalized expression for posterior density- recognize distribution

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, density-function, bayesian

Assume that each $Y_i$ has a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda_i$ where:
$$log(\lambda_i)=\alpha+\beta x_i$$
Moreover, we assume
$Y_1,...,Y_n$ are independent (given the parameters).
For the Bayessian approach, we are going to use the prior for $(\alpha,\beta)$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are
independent, and $\alpha \sim N(3,25)$ and  $\beta \sim N(0,1)$.

Now I have to write up an unnormalized expression for posterior density. Bayes rule give us:
$$p(\alpha,\beta|Y_1,...,Y_n)\propto p(\alpha)p(\beta) p(Y_1,...,Y_n|\alpha,\beta)\\
 $$
And then I get
$$p(Y_1,...,Y_n|\alpha,\beta)\propto  \exp(-\sum_i \lambda_i)\prod_{i}{\lambda_{i}}^{Y_i}\\
= \exp(- n\alpha-\beta\sum_i x_i)\prod_{i}{(\alpha+\beta x_i)}^{Y_i}
 $$
and
$$p(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{25}\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\alpha-3}{\sqrt{25}})^2}=\frac{1}{5 \sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{(\alpha-3)^2}{50}}$$
and
$$p(\beta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\beta-0}{\sqrt{1}})^2}=\frac{1}{ \sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{\beta^2}{2}}$$

Therefore we get that:
$$p(\alpha,\beta|Y_1,...,Y_n)\propto \frac{1}{5 \sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{(\alpha-3)^2}{50}}\frac{1}{ \sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{\beta^2}{2}}\exp(- n\alpha-\beta\sum_i x_i)\prod_{i}{(\alpha+\beta x_i)}^{Y_i}$$
Now I have to find out what distribution $p(Y_1,...,Y_n|\alpha,\beta)$ is. Can anyone help me?

Comment: In general, the posterior distribution won't be a "nice" named distribution for most choice of priors. That only happens in special cases, e.g.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior

Comment: I can't find Poisson distribution with normal distributed priors on the list. But I had make a simulation that indicates that posterior density is a normal distribution? Can you help me to understand that?

Comment: I'm saying it shouldn't be on this list because it's not one of the special cases. How confident are you it's normal from your simulation? It doesn't look like it from the posterior density because of the extra $\prod_i (\alpha + \beta x_i)^{Y_i}$ term.

Comment: Yeah you are right it was for beta I have just made a plot. But if I just then let the expression for that posterior density stay. But  can you help with what is the distribution of $p(Y_1,..., Y_n|\alpha, \beta)$? So I by simulation can make posterior
predictive draws of each $\tilde{Y_j}$